# Ruby: Array of Hashes *with duplicate keys* to Hash (recursive or deep reduce?)

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have an array of hashes

```
var = 
[
{#<InstanceFoo>=>{Date1=>Value1}}, 
{#<InstanceBar>=>{Date2=>Value2}},
{#<InstanceBaz>=>{Date3=>Value3}}
]
```

Which i would like to reduce to a Hash:

```
{
#<InstanceFoo>=>{Date1=>Value1}, 
#<InstanceBar>=>{Date2=>Value2},
#<InstanceBaz>=>{Date3=>Value3}
}
```

I have achieved this in the past with:

```
var.reduce({}, :merge)
```

I have just noticed an issue, however, `var` actually looks like this:

```
var = 
[
{#<InstanceFoo>=>{Date1=>nil}}, 
{#<InstanceFoo>=>{Date2=>Value2}},
{#<InstanceFoo>=>{Date3=>Value3}}
]
```

And the `reduce` results in the following:

```
var = 
{
  #<InstanceFoo>=>{Date1=>nil}
}
```

I would like to return:

```
var = 
{
  #<InstanceFoo>=>{Date1=>nil, Date2=>Value2, Date3=>Value3}
}
```

I suppose this is a recursive (or deep) merge? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var.reduce({}, :deep_merge)
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thanks